# How to display external links content in a dialog from Java Bean?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, myfaces, trinidad

I should display an external link content in a dialog dynamically.
I trayed this in my bean but it just opens a new tab. 
**Is there any other way to show the content of the external link in the dialog?**

I use Primefaces, Trinidad, and JSF in my pages and am open to using any other framework.
Any simple solution is very welcome.

in bean:

```
public void launchUrl(String url) {

        try {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }
```

in xhtml:

first method:

```
<tr:goButton id="evsButton1" text="eVS" onclick="openUrl('#{bean.url}')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
        function openUrl(url) {
          window.open(url,"_blank");
        }
      </script>
```

second method:

```
<tr:goButton id="evsButton" text="eVS" destination="#{bean.url}" targetFrame="_blank" attributeChangeListener="#{wijzigBean.fetchUrl}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be possible to add the external content as an iframe

```
 <div id="someId"> 
    <iframe id="iframeId" name="iframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" src="#{yourbean.externalUrl}">
       <p>Something went wrong.</p>
    </iframe>
 </div>
```

from [Adding iframe to JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262799/adding-iframe-to-jsf-components)

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I used it en with a combination of Trinidad dialog as below. `
`String viewId = "/popups/evs.xhtml";
  TrinidadDialog dialog = new TrinidadDialog
    .Builder(viewId, event.getComponent())
    .window().size(800, 600)
    .parameter(KMEHR_MESSAGE_PARAMETER, evsUrl)
    .build();

  dialog.open();` I am going to accept your answer.